# How to export complex class with boost.python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have an event class I am trying to make accessible in python using Boost.Python.  Here is the listing, along with associated macros and an example derived event class.

```
class Event
{
  private:
    unsigned __int64 m_TimeStamp;

  public:
    // Empty parameter struct used as base for event parameters
    //  in derived classes.
    struct Params { };

    Event();

    virtual unsigned int Type() const = 0;
    virtual const char* TypeName() const = 0;

    unsigned __int64 TimeStamp() const { return m_TimeStamp; }
};

typedef shared_ptr<Event> EventPtr;

#define DECLARE_EVENTTYPE(typeName, id)                                   \
  enum { TYPE = id };                                                     \
  unsigned int Type() const     { return static_cast<unsigned int>(id); } \
  const char* TypeName() const  { return typeName;          }

// Macro used to declare the start of an event parameters structure
#define START_EVENTPARAMS()     struct Params : public Event::Params {

// Macro used to finish the event parameters structure declaration
#define END_EVENTPARAMS(eventName)                                        \
  } m_Params;                                                             \
  eventName(const Event::Params* pkParams = NULL) : Event()               \
  {                                                                       \
    if (NULL != pkParams)                                                 \
    {                                                                     \
      const eventName::Params* pkEventParams =                            \
        reinterpret_cast<const eventName::Params*>(pkParams);             \
      if (NULL != pkEventParams)                                          \
        m_Params = *pkEventParams;                                        \
    }                                                                     \
  }                                                                       \
  static const eventName::Params& Parameters(const EventPtr pkEvent)      \
  {                                                                       \
    const shared_ptr<eventName> pkErrorEvent(                             \
      dynamic_pointer_cast<eventName>(pkEvent));                          \
    return pkErrorEvent->m_Params;                                        \
  }

// Macro used for events that have no parameters
#define EVENT_NOPARAMS(eventName)                                         \
  eventName(const Event::Params*) : Event() { }

struct ExampleEvent : public Event
{
  START_EVENTPARAMS()
    std::string m_strMsg;
  END_EVENTPARAMS(ExampleEvent)

  DECLARE_EVENTTYPE("ExampleEvent", 1);
};
```

The intention is I want to be able to derive python based event classes from this one, however the mechanism for declaring and using event parameters is embedded in the macros.  Frankly I don't think the way it is setup in C++ will work in python anyway, as any parameters an event would have in python would likely be stored in a dictionary.

Is there a way to export this functionality using boost.python, or is there a better way to design the class for generic parameter support that will work well in C++ and in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately there's no real way for Python to create new C++ types, which is essentially what you're asking. If you want to be able to create new event types in Python which are on equal footing with what you can create in C++, then you'll need a more dynamic, Python-like structure in C++.

If your requirement really is that this works only in C++ and Python (i.e. you don't intend to extend this to other languages) then you might consider storing your event parameters in a `boost::python::dict` instead of as individual data members. You'll need to use `boost::python::extract<>` in C++ to access the values, but otherwise it's a pretty clean system. (And you can probably hide the extract call inside a templated accessor method.)

Another option is to access event parameters with a getter, e.g. `Event::get_param<T>("name")`. If you make this virtual then Python-based implementation of events can provide their own version.